# How to include project file in solution in Visual Studio for Windows but not on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio

Our solution contains a project type not supported on VsMac. It's a data tier app. In the solution file, there's the reference to the project:

```
Project("{00D1A9C2-B5F0-4AF3-8072-F6C62B433612}") = "SqlData", "Data\SqlData\SqlData.sqlproj", "{707B86CA-45F7-43C4-A9A4-CC2687E82056}"
EndProject
```

Is it possible to have this include for Windows versions of Visual Studio only?

The only option I'm aware of would be to use a separate *.sln file which is not optimal.